# What is equalivent of 'chrome://settings/passwords' for firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want to get a password I am using in `firefox`.

In chrome I can use `chrome://settings/password` and get the password I need.

How do I do this in `firefox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new tab, click the gear, click "Privacy & Security," scroll down to "Forms & Passwords," click the button that says "Saved Logins" and find the one you want to change or view that should do it.

Please note that I am on Windows.

Edit: Seems that "Forms & Passwords" has changed to "Logins & Passwords"

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu -> options -> privacy & security -> Saved Logins...

Comment: I am on mac, and dont have the menu option.

Comment: on mac go to preferences, click privacy & security and search for saved logins